# google drive PHP : how to list complete subtree of the folder

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How to get basic info (id, title, mime-type at least) for each file and folder in subtree of given folder with as few API-calls as possible? ie. not to call api to download details for every subfolder?

I found the workaround to read all files with some non-hierarchical-characteristic (eg. owner) and to build tree-structure in client script. My files are unfortunately all from one owner (application), so I cannot do it this way.

---

ok, here is the example code for the recursion-multiple-api-calls way, which can be enough for some use cases. But I would like to find better concept (not to discuss this implementation, but another way, how to not call the API for each folder):

```
class Foo {

const FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder';


public function getSubtreeForFolder($parentId, $sort=true)
{
    $service = $this->createCrmGService();

    // A. folder info
    $file = $service->files->get($parentId);
    $ret = array(
        'id' => $parentId,
        'name' => $file->getTitle(),
        'description' => $file->getDescription(),
        'mimetype' => $file->getMimeType(),
        'is_folder' => true,
        'children' => array(),
        'node' => $file,
    );

    if ($ret['mimetype'] != self::FOLDER_MIME_TYPE) {
        throw new Exception(_t("{$ret['name']} is not a folder."));
    }

    $items = $this->findAllFiles($queryString='trashed = false', $parentId, $fieldsFilter='items(alternateLink,description,fileSize,id,mimeType,title)', $service); 

    foreach ($items as $child)
    {
        if ($this->isFolder($child)) 
        {
            $ret['children'][] = $this->getSubtreeForFolder($child->id, $sort);
        }

        else
        {
            // B. file info
            $a['id'] = $child->id;
            $a['name'] = $child->title;
            $a['description'] = $child->description;
            $a['is_folder'] = false;
            $a['url'] = $file->getDownloadUrl();
            $a['url_detail'] = $child->getAlternateLink();
            $a['versionLabel'] = false; //FIXME
            $a['node'] = $child;

            if (!$a['versionLabel']) {
                $a['versionLabel'] = '1.0'; //old files compatibility hack
            }
            $ret['children'][] = $a;
        }
    }

    if ($sort && isset($ret['children'])) 
    {
        if ($sort === true) {
            $sort = create_function('$a, $b', 'if ($a[\'name\'] == $b[\'name\']) return 0; return strcasecmp($a[\'name\'], $b[\'name\']);');
        }
        usort($ret['children'], $sort);
    }

    return $ret;
}


public function findAllFiles($queryString, $parentId=false, $fieldsFilter='items(id,title)', $service = false) 
{
    if (!$service)  $service = $this->createCrmGService();

    $result = array();
    $pageToken = NULL;

    if ($parentId) {
        $queryString .= ($queryString ? ' AND ' : '') . "'{$parentId}' in parents";
    }

    do {
        try {

            $parameters = array('q' => $queryString);

            if ($fieldsFilter) $parameters['fields'] = $fieldsFilter;

            if ($pageToken) {
                $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }

            $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

            $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());

            $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
            $pageToken = NULL;
        }
    } while ($pageToken);

    return $result;
}


    /**
     * @param Google_DriveFile $file
     * @return boolean, jestli je $file slozka.
     */
    protected function isFolder($file)
    {
        return $file->getMimeType() == self::FOLDER_MIME_TYPE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Google's products API in general have an excelent documentation. Start from there: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php and https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get.

Comment: Thank You, but I really read this documentation and put this question because I haven't found solution. Have I missed something?

Comment: I think so. Look at this reference page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list and this shows how to get the response(complete) from a list of files: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: This example reads a list = all childs of root folder. Problem is how to effectivly read a tree (so every subfolder, their subfolders, etc.).
We can implement recursion this way, so for every folder to make a new call to Google API - to list this subfolder childs. But this is not effective, more worse with every subfolder (another API call).
Someone sugests to read ALL files and because this brings you also the parent info, you can build the tree with one API call in client script. But if You have too many files, You just cannot read them all.
I hope it is more clear (sorry for my english)

Comment: it would be nice to have "recursive=true" parameter

Comment: I got your point. I'm trying to help you with the docs, but with the API itself, I can go any further cause I have no experience on it and I can't test a scenario right now. I would suggest you try anything and post your code here to get more attention.

Comment: Ok, I have added code example to question (It seems I cannot add this long text other way as a new user here). But I would like to find different approach.

Comment: Nice. You done right. I can't help you now but if later, nobody helped, I will try when I get at home. Good luck.

Comment: Thats ok, I don't want You to do the work for me. There has to be someone who already solved it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest you not to get all files and folders. It takes too much time for some users who have many files uploaded on their Drive. Also, there is query limit in your application key. In fact, many applications who have custom file picker make queries each time user requests subfolder.

Second, if this is webapp, it would be better idea to use [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). Google Picker is way much faster and more efficient to pick files from Drive. There are many options and filters and you have decent control over files.

Third, you cannot fully represent Drive's files and folders in tree structure. As you can see in queries, each file have **parents**, which means there can be more than one parent for each file/folder. You need to think of some workarounds like choosing only one of the parents for each file.

If you still want to get all file/folder information, in terms of performance, the best implementation would be recursively calling [Children.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list). FYI, file id 'root' is reserved id you can easily start with. And once you get id's of children, you can make batch query of [Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) with multipart. This is the fastest way to traverse through file system of Google Drive afaik.

Again, unless you have very good reason, please do not try to traverse through all files in Drive at once. There are some users who have a lot of files in their Drive and you will make them wait forever no matter how great optimization you made. Also, you will easily hit query limit.

Comment: Thanks JunYoung for lots of interesting info! I actually do not traverse through all files. It is CRM entity that has it's folder in Gdrive. I need to display only subtree for this entity's folder (there never is more then tens of files, and I always need only theirs metadata). Because this is an application widget with some context info I am not sure if I can use G.Picker, but I definitely check out this and especially the way with "Files.get() with multipart". Thanks!